# Rails overwriting rel attribute when supplying method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rel

In Rails 3, when utilizing the `method` attribute of a `link_to`, my custom `rel` value is being overwritten.

```
# my code:
link_to 'Add to Favorites',
  profile_favorites_path(profile),
  :method => :post,
  :class => 'button',
  :rel => 'favorite'

# expected result:
<a href="/profiles/1/favorites" class="button" data-method="post" rel="favorite nofollow">Add to Favorites</a>

# actual result:
<a href="/profiles/1/favorites" class="button" data-method="post" rel="nofollow">Add to Favorites</a>
```

Is this a Rails bug / unexpected feature?  How can I make use of the built-in `method` functionality while also supplying a custom `rel` value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems you can only specify the `rel` attribute if the `method` is set to get.

Inside `action_view/helpers/url_helper.rb` `add_method_to_attributes!` you can see the logic rails is currently using for this:

```
def add_method_to_attributes!(html_options, method)
  html_options["rel"] = "nofollow" if method && method.to_s.downcase != "get"
  html_options["data-method"] = method if method
end
```

This actually makes sense, you wouldn't want to have bots/spiders posting when crawling links.

Comment: You're correct that I don't want bots/spiders following post URL's.  However, you're supposed to be able to have rel contain multiple values.  So even if it equalled "favorite nofollow", which is what I expected it to be, spiders wouldn't follow the link since it still contains "nofollow".